# Crash button if statement xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, device

i have an issue with xamarin for android.

In my app, after i click a button, i want to play two statements. One, when EditTexts are emptys, and else when the editTexts are not empty.

My app always crash for the first statement and not for the second.

You can see my code bellow.

```
Button generate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.generate);

generate.Click += Generate_Click;

private void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
EditText inputMin = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inputMin);
EditText inputMax = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inputMax);

minimum = int.Parse(inputMin.Text);
maximum = int.Parse(inputMax.Text);

string minString = inputMin.Text;
string maxString = inputMax.Text;

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(minString) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(maxString))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Enter a minimum and a maximum value", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Console.WriteLine("check input empty");
        }

else { do this }

}
```

I don't know why it's crashing.

Any help?

Thanks a lot!

Regards, Sam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most times, the `int.Parse` is the problem.

Please, try to use `int.TryParse`.

For example:

```
Button generate = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.generate);

generate.Click += Generate_Click;

private void Generate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   EditText inputMin = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inputMin);
   EditText inputMax = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.inputMax);

   int minimum, maximum;

   if(!int.TryParse(inputMin.Text, out minimum) && int.TryParse(inputMax.Text, out maximum))
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Parsing problem!");
      // return;                                <--- If you want to stop.
   }

   string minString = inputMin.Text;
   string maxString = inputMax.Text;

   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(minString) || String.IsNullOrEmpty(maxString))
   {
      Toast.MakeText(this, "Enter a minimum and a maximum value", 
                     ToastLength.Long).Show();
      Console.WriteLine("check input empty");
   }
   else 
   { 
      // do this 
   }
}
```

Comment: when i use your solution, and i click on the generate button with editTexts empty, i had this error "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format." then the app crashed.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the return statement? The exception is call ed because your string is empty!? But with my solution you shouldn't get this exception, because the TRYParse.

Comment: Do you set your maximum again in this else from a string? Perhaps, you can update your question with a code snippet?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to edit my text again, but it works fine. Thanks a lot!